# Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{z^2}$

Tags: fractions, laurent-series

I need to find a Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{z^2}$ with centre in $z_0 = 1$ and $P(1, 2014, 2015)$.

If it was $\frac{1}{z}$, I'd rewrite the fraction like this:

$$
\frac{1}{(z-1) +1 } 
$$

But with $z^2$ I'm not sure how to proceed...

#### My attempt:

According to the given recommendation, I've tried to do the expansion of $\frac{1}{z}$:

$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{1+(z-1)},  a_{0} = 1, q = -(z-1) = 1-z 
$$

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(1-z)^{n} = 1 + (1-z) + (1-z)^2 + ...
$$

And after differentiation:
$$
0 + 1 + 2(1-z) + 3(1-z)^2 + ... = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}n(1-z)^{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Find the laurent expansion of $1/z$ and differentiate.

Comment: I've added my attempt into the description. Is it okay? And is the sum supposed to be from $-\infty$ or from $0$? And thank you very much, of course.

Comment: $1/z^2$ is holomorphic at $z = 1$, so the coefficients of the negative exponents in the laurent expansion will all be equal to $0$, so you can take the sum starting from $n=0$. Also, the laurent expansion should have the standard form, i.e. $1/z^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} (z-1)^{n}$. Also, you forgot to take the inner derivatives into account (minus signs!)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

$\dfrac {1}{z^2}=\dfrac {\left(1-\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^2}{(z-1)^2}=
\dfrac {(1-z)^2+2(1-z)^3+3(1-z)^4+4(1-z)^5+  \ldots}{(1-z)^2}=1+2(1-z)+3(1-z)^2+4(1-z)^3+ \ldots$

using the product of convergent power series.